# Blob download not working with JavaScript inside a WebView

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, webview, blob

I have a React application which needs to support both WebViews and Browsers. I have a functionality where-in we have an API which returns base64String and we need to convert it to PDF and provide a link to user to download the PDF. Below is a sample code snippet.

Code Snippet:

```js
const convertBase64StringToPDF = (data: string) => {
  const byteCharacters = atob(data);
  const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
    byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
  return new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
};


getbase64StringData(baseUrl2)
  .then((response) => {
    const blob = convertBase64StringToPDF(response.foobar);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = 'MyDoc' + new Date() + '.pdf';
    link.click();
  })
```

The problem I'm facing is when a user clicks on the link we create, the download isn't getting triggered only in WebViews. I searched for solutions but most of them suggest making changes in WebView code. Problem is I don't have control over the App code which has the WebView embedded in it. Is there a way I can solve this in React/JavaScript application? I don't care where the download happens, I just need it to get triggered and get stored in users device.